# if Is_Pend=true and Is_Hold=true If true then these items should be displayed at the end

Tags: extjs

I have a issue . I am getting store which contain create data,is_pend,Is_Hold,name,address etc. I am not able to push the row witch meet criteria   if( Is_Pend=true and Is_Hold=true ) @ bottom of store. ie 
If true then these items should be displayed at the end of store.
I try but not resolve the eg like this ............                                 store= Title    DirectorReleased    Is_Pend  Is_held
Troop   Chandra 27/12/2052  FALSE   TRUE
Office  Mike    9/8/2011    TRUE    TRUE
Office  Mike    19/02/2009  TRUE    FALSE
Sur Jay 8/12/2002   FALSE   TRUE
Supers  Jekhar  8/6/2002    FALSE   FALSE
Super   Jay 15/02/2002  FALSE   FALSE
Supers  Jay 27/01/2002  TRUE    TRUE
Super   Jay 28/12/1992  FALSE   FALSE  is store then this  will come like ..............................................                                     Title  DirectorReleased    Is_Pend  Is_held
Troopers Chan   27/12/2052  FALSE   TRUE
Sur Jay 8/12/2002   TRUE    FALSE
Supers  Jekhar  8/6/2002    FALSE   FALSE
Super   Jay 15/02/2002  FALSE   FALSE
Super   Jay 28/12/1992  FALSE   FALSE
Office  Mike    19/02/2009  TRUE    TRUE
Office  Mike    9/8/2011    TRUE    TRUE
Supers  Jay 27/01/2002  TRUE    TRUE
  after pushing row of the above store

Comment: Do you mean some kind of sorting?

Comment: The question is unclear and badly formatter. Could you please improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom sorting function, see: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-sortType

Comment: Title Director Released  Is_Pend  Is_held
Troopers Chandrasekhar 27/12/2052 FALSE TRUE
Office Mike 9/8/2011 TRUE TRUE
Office Mike 19/02/2009 TRUE FALSE
Sur Jay 8/12/2002 FALSE TRUE
Supers Jekhar 8/6/2002 FALSE FALSE
Super Jay 15/02/2002 FALSE FALSE
Supers Jay 27/01/2002 TRUE TRUE
Super Jay 28/12/1992 FALSE FALSE